# Docker Quickstart Terminal: exit status 255

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

Docker version 1.12.2, build bb80604

When I try to launch docker quickstart terminal, I am getting below error. Can anyone please provide inputs to solve this problem?

```
Error checking TLS connection: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :




                    ##         .
              ## ## ##        ==
           ## ## ## ## ##    ===
       /"""""""""""""""""\___/ ===
  ~~~ {~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~~~~ ~~~ ~ /  ===- ~~~
       \______ o           __/
         \    \         __/
          \____\_______/

Error getting IP address: Something went wrong running an SSH command!
command : ip addr show
err     : exit status 255
output  :
docker is configured to use the default machine with IP
For help getting started, check out the docs at https://docs.docker.com

Start interactive shell
```

Comment: Are you using docker-machine? Please see if this helps - https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/66

Comment: I am using DockerToolbox in windows.

Answer (score 2):

I have removed the default instance and re-created one with below commands, it worked for me.

```
$ docker-machine rm default
$ docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

Comment: although obvious, one should keep in mind that **this will delete all docker volumes** and their data.

Answer (score 2):

I did this commands(from Prasad Revanaki), but is not ok yet, when I send a "docker ps" a recieve:

`error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.33/containers
/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. I
n the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not run ning.`

then I run my docker quickstart terminal ***in administration mode*** and ***stop one image that was in virtual box running*** and finally now it is ok.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Recently got this problem with my docker (VirtualBox + Windows 10). It was after some reconfiguration of virtual machine network (host only networks and NAT). Managed to fix it without removing the default VM.

Symptoms:

command

```
docker-machine ls
```

returns timeout error, and command

```
docker-machine ssh default
```

returns error 255

With -D switch (e.g. docker-machine -D ssh default) I saw that it was trying to connect to localhost (127.0.0.1), port 22, whereas the default vm runs on 192.168.56.101 or 192.168.99.101 (I have two host only networks and one NAT in my setup).

After I've configured port 22 forwarding from 192.168.56.101 to 127.0.0.1 (also 22), it has started working fine.

[image: virtual machine network configuration]
[image: ssh port forwarding from the default vm to host' localhost]

Successful ls call:
[image: docker-machine ls proper output]

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ docker-machine rm -y default; docker-machine create -d virtualbox default
```

BUT, 
I had to do it twice, because I had the VM running.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across the same issue recently and the solution was different than all the ones posted here or on github. In my case the reason was that port 1119 was already randomly assigned by `jhi_service.exe`, which is an Intel app.

If you start the VM through VirtualBox you will not be able to figure that out. At some point I tried running the Docker Quickstart Terminal with VM down and got the error message about port 1119 already taken. All you need then is `netstat -a -b -n -o`, finding the culprit and killing it:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:1119         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3436
 [jhi_service.exe]
```